# What shell cmd to launch directory in MAC OS X

Tags: .net, macos

What shell command can i use to launch/open a folder in mac os x?
I will be executing it in .NET

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[open](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/open.1.html)

Answer (score 2):

"open" with a folder argument will open finder with given folder opened. With files it will use the default file associated.

ie

open ~/Documents/